# Can I end a Promise.each early?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

```
db.Question.findAll({
  where: {
    PassageId: dbPassage.id,
    active: true,
    level: {
      $lte: startLevel,
      $gte: endLevel
    }
  },
  order: [db.Sequelize.fn('RANDOM')]
}).each(function(dbQuestion) {
  // End early if some condition
});
```

I'm using `bluebird` and I want to know if it's possible to abort out of an `.each` early?

Comment: what have u tried? what was the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like that. (not tested)

```
var searchPromise = Promise.resolve();

searchPromise = db.Question.findAll({
  where: {
    PassageId: dbPassage.id,
    active: true,
    level: {
      $lte: startLevel,
      $gte: endLevel
    }
  },
  order: [db.Sequelize.fn('RANDOM')]
}).each(function(dbQuestion) {
  if (condition === true) {
    searchPromise.cancel();
  }
}).cancellable();
```